# how to update a binary field in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm working in a self proyect to put it in my portfolio, is a facebook clone made it with fastapi, sqlalchemy and postgresql with frontend using boostrap and a little bit of javascript, not so fancy but i want to make an edit post feauture, but when a i want to put a new image to my media field it raise an error "can't scape str to binary", of curse i use uploadFile class from fastapi and use the method read to get the data and then put in a dict, i use the same method to create a post, but for update it doest'n work, i would like to use pydantic for this but with pydantic riase other error when i try to use bytes type.

```
#This is the endpoint 

@router.post("/edit-post/{id}")
async def edit_post(request: Request, id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    form = post_form(request)

    await form.load_data()

    post = r_get_post(db,id)
     
    
    #getting the post if the the data in the form is not valid return to the html with the post info
    if post.media:
        image = base64.b64encode(post.media)
        post.media = image.decode()
        
    
    if await form.validate_data():
        current_user: User_response = get_current_user(request, db)
        media = None 
        if form.__dict__.get("media"):
            media = await form.__dict__.get("media").read()
       
        
        post_update = {"content":form.content,"media":media}
        r_update_post(post_update,db,current_user.id,id)
        
        return responses.RedirectResponse("/",status_code=status.HTTP_302_FOUND)
    else:
        form.__dict__.update({"post":post})
        return templates.TemplateResponse(
            "posts/edit_post.html",form.__dict__
        )

#This is where i try to update:


def r_update_post(post, db: Session, user_id: int, post_id: int):
    post_query = (
        db.query(Post).filter(Post.id == post_id).filter(Post.owner_id == user_id)
    )
    
    post_query.update({Post.content:post['content'],Post.media:post["media"]}, synchronize_session=False)
    
    db.commit()
```

I been reading official documentation but i got nothing really helpful and go to github and here in this site, by the way i'm sorry if my english is bad, is not my mother lenguage, but i really would appreciate if someone can help me